# What is the location of stdlib.h in XCode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

Please tell me, what is the location of stdlib.h in XCode 4.3 ?

Comment: can't say about 4.3, but on my machine with XCode 4.2 `locate stdlib.h | grep /stdlib\.h$` outputs
`/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h`
`/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h`
`/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h`
`/usr/include/stdlib.h`

Comment: @darkmist Apple have bundled Xcode 4.3 to the single application package, and now it's quite hard to find things...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What was in `/Developer` in Xcode versions prior to 4.3 is now within the `Xcode.app` bundle.  There are several, one for each supported SDK and Platform:

```
$ find /Applications/Xcode.app -name stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdlib.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You have told me not only where to find it, but also about a great way to find other header files!

Answer (score 5):

If you install the command line tools (Xcode > Preferences > Downloads), then the file is present at`/usr/include/stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using `unistd.h` instead of `stdlib.h`.  I had an issue trying to use sleep() when importing `stdlib.h` and I had to import `unistd.h`.

Comment: [stdlib](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdlib.h.html) is specified by POSIX. You should not have to work around it. bames53 (below) had the correct answer (general solution, even for non-Xcode command line builds). trojanfoe (above) answered a question that was not asked (relating to Xcode builds). Also, sometimes you don't have that kind of latitude (stdlib.h -> unistd.h)